# TypeError: Illuminate\Validation\Factory::make(): Argument #3 ($messages) must be of type array, null given

Tags: laravel

so I am creating some kind of Company Management API.
Momentarily, I've managed to run up into a bug.
When I try to test my create function for creating new Companies, in Postman I get a bug of this kind:

> TypeError: Illuminate\Validation\Factory::make(): Argument #3 ($messages) must be of type array, null given

I know my bug is in my Form Request and I tried solving it but couldn't come up to a solution. Here is my Controller code:

```
 public function create(CompanyRequest $request) {
    return $this->companyService->create($request);
}
```

Here is my Service code:

```
public function create(CompanyRequest $request){
        $company = $this->companyRepository->create($request->all());
        return new CompanyResource($company);
    }
```

Here is my Company Request code:

```
  public function rules()
    {
       return [
            'name' => 'required|string|max:50'
    ];
    }
```

And here is my Company Resource code:

```
   public function toArray($request)
    {
        return [
            'name' => $this->name
        ];
    }
}
```

I just started learning Laravel 2-3 months ago and this is some random API that I am creating, any help would be welcomed.

Comment: Can you share the `companyRepository` `create` function code ?

Comment: @mhmdomer Yes, 
I don't have anything in my CompanyRepository besides my construct function, but my companyRepository extends my BaseRepository which has this create function: 

 `public function create($data)
    {
        return $this->model->create($data);} `

Answer (score 0):

In your **service code**, can you replace `$request->all()` to `$request->validated()`.

```
public function create(CompanyRequest $request){
    $company = $this->companyRepository->create($request->validated());
    return new CompanyResource($company);
}
```

Below is the snippet taken from the docs https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/validation#creating-form-requests

```
// Retrieve the validated input data...
$validated = $request->validated();
```

Comment: I tried it, it's still the same

Comment: for debugging purposes, can you change this line of code from `return new CompanyResource($company);`  to `return $company` ?

Comment: It still return the same things, tf